# How to access a disabled button in reactjs and alter its CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, button

I have a button like so:

```
<button className="button1" disabled={!this.validateForm()} type="submit" onClick={sig => this.handleCreation(sig, this.state)}>Action</button>
```

I want to access it's CSS when it is `disabled` so I can alter the way it looks - I have already altered it in the default state in the CSS for the `button` class. How do I do that? the `:disabled` selector of CSS doesn't work (obviously).

Comment: Using `.button1:disabled` in your CSS will work perfectly fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-sound-efjus

Comment: I should note I altered the `validateForm()` so that it makes the form of `controlled` input, it's fairly easy and there's a lot of tutorials on it and a long documentation about it online.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to alter the style.One way would look like this

```
<button className={isDisabled?'new-style':'old-style'} .../>
```

Comment: isDisabled you can get from this.validateForm in your case

Comment: Thank you, this solved my issue in one line! Amazing!

Comment: This works, but I (respectfully) disagree that this is a "better" way. In my opinion the better way is as Chris G suggests in his comment on the question... have two CSS styles (not two classes), first `.button { something }` and then `.button:disabled { something-else }`

Comment: I had used this way more often.It would be helpful if i could know when to use one particular way.Any pros and cons in each of the answers?

Comment: I use a pseudo class instead of an alternate class when an appropriate pseudo class exists; `:disabled` is the perfect example of that. When there's not a pseudo class I avoid alternate classes ... say you have a class `.address` and two classes, `.hidden` and `.showing` (I've seen people do this) — you have to remove _hidden_ **and** add _showing_. And what does it mean if _both_ classes end up on the element? Instead, just have `.hidden` which you add/remove. Style the plain thing `.address` then modify using `.address.hidden` or just `.hidden { display: none; }` if it's for wide use (more)

Comment: But then why use `.hidden` at all? Instead ask yourself _why_ it's hidden, and that _why_ is a better class name. Maybe you have a `.shop` and when the shop is closed you hide it. `class="shop hidden"`… better is `class="shop closed"` then you can `display:none` when `.shop.closed` and even better, when you change your mind and want it _dimmed_ instead of hidden, `.shop.closed` still makes sense, while `.shop.hidden` doesn't. You'd have to find every `.hidden` and change it to `.dim` — Name classes for what things _**are**_, not how they _look_. ("are" could be what it **is**, or a **state**)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation !